# Can't get the most basic scrollview to work

Tags: xcode

This is not my day. I've just deleted every object from my previously completed view controller to start over because I can't get a simple scroll view to scroll. I've got a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. I put scroll view inside the view controller and then put two text fields inside the scroll view, one field at the top and one at the bottom.

First of all, when I run this, it won't scroll. What is the point of the scroll view if it won't scroll?

Second, I can't figure out how the relationship between the navigation bar and the scroll view works. Is the scroll view *behind* the navigation bar? Is it *below* the navigation bar? In the story board, it looks like it is behind the bar, but when I run it, my text field is pushed down so far that it looks like it is behind it.

Here are a couple of screen shots. To say that I am frustrated is an understatement. Thanks for any help getting me out of my circular problem. I appreciate it.

[image]

And here is how it looks when I run it. Notice how far down the top text field gets drawn. Also note that you cannot see the bottom text field. I am unable to scroll to this. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, when I run this, it won't scroll. What is the point of the scroll view if it won't scroll?

Scroll views won't scroll by default unless their `contentSize` exceeds their `bounds`.  You can force it to scroll anyway by setting `alwaysBounceVertical` to `YES`.

> Second, I can't figure out how the relationship between the navigation bar and the scroll view works. Is the scroll view behind the navigation bar? Is it below the navigation bar? In the story board, it looks like it is behind the bar, but when I run it, my text field is pushed down so far that it looks like it is behind it.

Yes, in iOS 7, by default, a scroll view will start at y = 0, behind the nav bar.  You use the `contentInsets` property to push it down.  The view controller has an `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property that can handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks for that information. It helps quite a bit. If the scroll view starts at 0, I can push it down at run time easily enough using `contentInsets`. But doesn't that mean that when I am working in the storyboard then I have to put my objects behind the nav bar, which means that I can't see them there because the nav bar is covering them up? That just seems crazy to me. I must be missing something. Also, as for the scrollview, when I turn the view to landscape, the contentSize clearly exceeds the bounds of the scroll view, but it still won't scroll. Thus, my frustration. Thanks again!

Comment: If the scroll view won't scroll, either `contentSize` is not bigger than `bounds`, or something like `scrollEnabled` or `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO`.  And as far as your storyboard concerns… this is why I write all my views in code. :)

Comment: I think that I might have to go that route. I'm starting to believe that AutoLayout is Apple's cruel joke on the world.